# Is $\Bbb Q^n$ dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

It is well known that the rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$, are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

**My question here** :Is $\ \mathbb{Q}^n$ dense  in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$ ?

**Edit** : I edited the question as it is related to the precedent question.

Thank you for any help .

Comment: What ideas do you have about this problem that you might use?

Comment: i asked this question beacuse it is well known at all that Q dense In R but what about Q² in R² , i would like to see what about advenced theory in Algebra give to me for this ?

Comment: We usually like to know what you think might work in your problem before giving a complete solution.

Comment: Can you prove that any rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$ contains elements of $\mathbb Q^2$? (This is equivalent to $\mathbb Q^2$ being dense.)

Answer (score 6):

That is pretty trivial. If $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, for any $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we may find $(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ such that $|x_i-q_i|\leq\varepsilon$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, so $\|x-q\|_1\leq n\varepsilon $ is arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, the product of dense sets is dense in the product topology.

For a proof, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794832/cartesian-product-of-dense-sets-is-dense).