# Is $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

I know that there is always an irrational number between any two rational points on the real line but is there a similar result in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: What is the closure of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Daniel would it be $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ since the closure of each component would be $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Yes, it would be, and you have your answer then :)

Comment: How would the proof for that work? Is the closure of each component of a Cartesian product equal to the Cartesian product of closures?

Comment: Sequences in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ look like $(x_n,y_n)$ where $x_n, y_n\in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$. If you give me an element of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ say $(a,b)$, then I can find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a$ and a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n\rightarrow b$. In other words you have a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ whose limit is $(a,b)$ for any $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Daniel that makes sense. It would seem that I over thought this. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ are sets, not topological spaces. you need to define a topology on those, for example a distance (or a norm and an addition) so that you can talk of neighborhoods, of converging sequences, and hence of closure and if one is dense in another.

Comment: @user1952009 for this, I planned to assume the usual topology though I forgot to mention it in my question.

Comment: what I mean is that depending on the topology, the result for the density will be different

Comment: @user1952009 so what would the result be if the Euclidean metric with the usual topology was taken into account, specifically?

Comment: what do you think ?

Comment: More generally, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794832/cartesian-product-of-dense-sets-is-dense.

Comment: @user1952009 my guess: there would be a a sequence of elements of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ that would converge to an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ since the sequences would end up within an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of the limit. I would guess that if the limit had components of any real number then a small neighborhood would still contain elements of both the irrational a and rationals.

Comment: yes, where is the problem ? you proved that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the closure of  $\mathbb{Q}^2$ for the euclidian distance $d$ , hence $(\mathbb{Q}^2,d)$ is dense in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ and conversely.

Comment: @user1952009 does this not hold in general? I would suspect that not to be the case since the product topology isn't simply the Cartesian products of open sets.

Comment: lol. when the topology is induced by a norm on a vector space, it clearly always works when considering the cartesian product of a finite number of vector spaces. do you really care  ? (if you are not sure how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ there are more important questions you should study first...)

Answer (score 2):

Any non-empty open set $U$ in $\Bbb R^2$ contains an open disk, and that again contains an open rectangle $]a,b[\times ]c,d[$. There is a rational $q\in]a,b[$ and a rational $r\in]c,d[$. Then $(q,r)\in U$.