# (Dual Question) Dense subsets of Limit

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $(X_n,\pi_{n,k})$ be a countable [projective system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#Algebraic_objects) of separable topological spaces, where each $\pi_{n,m}$ is surjective.  Suppose that $D_n$ is a dense subset of $X_n$.

Is there a *reasonable/known* description of the finest topology on the underlying set of $\varprojlim X_n$ making $D\triangleq \bigcap_{n} \pi_n(D_n)\neq \emptyset$ dense? Here $\pi_n$ is the canonical (surjective) map taking $X_n$ onto $\varprojlim  X_n$.

*Thoughts*:
Such a topology must exist, since the intersections of topologies is a topology and since the trivial topology on the underlying set of $\varprojlim X_n$ ensures that there is a non-empty set of topologies on the underlying set of $\varprojlim X_n$ satisfying the question.

*Edit*:  It was brought to my attention that the original formulation of this question was already answered some time-ago [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043803/inverse-limit-of-dense-subsets-is-dense).

*Note:* This is the ~Dual of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454981/dense-subsets-of-colimit/3455177#3455177).

Comment: Have you seen [this counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3043956/4280)? In that example the intersection is empty.

Comment: Yes, Paul just brought this to my attention, so I modified the question (since it is a duplicate).

Comment: Even the trivial topology does not have this property: If the intersection $D$ is empty, then $\overline D = \emptyset$ for any topology.

Comment: Fair enough, but say I know that the intersection is non-empty.

Comment: inverse and direct limist behave quite differently, just as subspaces and quotients do. So don't let that have any weight.

Comment: Taking the intersections of topologies yields a topology, but it is the coarsest topology having the desired property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you ask the following question:

Given a non-empty subset $D$ of a set $X$, is there a finest topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $D$ becomes dense in $(X,\tau)$?

The case $D = X$ is trivial, the  discrete topology will do. Thus let us assume $D \subsetneqq X$.

If $D =\{x\}$ is a singleton, then we take $\tau$ to be the set of all $U \subset X$ such that $x \in U$ (plus the empty set). This has the desired property.

If $D$ has more than one point, then the answer is "no".

Let $x \in D$.  Then $\tau_1 = \{\emptyset, X \setminus \{x\}, X \}$ and $\tau_2 = \{\emptyset, (X \setminus D) \cup \{x\}, X \}$ are two topologies such that $D$ is dense in $(X,\tau_i)$. Now assume that there is a finest topology $\tau$ with this property. Then $\tau_i \subset \tau$, thus $X \setminus \{x\},(X \setminus D) \cup \{x\}$ belong to $\tau$ and so does their intersection $U = (X \setminus \{x\}) \cap ((X \setminus D) \cup \{x\}) = X \setminus D$. But $U$ does not contain any point of $D$, thus $D$ is not dense in $(X,\tau)$, a contradiction.

Comment: I've been thinking about this and is there, in general, produce a Hausdorff topology on $X$ making $D$ dense, given that $D$ is sufficiently regular?

Comment: So you ask whether there is a Hausdorfff topology on $X$ such that $D$ becomes dense? If so, it is a completely new question.

Comment: I think you're right.  I've posted the question here (in case you're interested):
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732461/hausdorff-topology-producing-density