# Hausdorff Topology Producing Density

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a infinite-dimensional vector space with countable basis and $D$ be a *given* infinite subset of $X$.  What are the minimal requirements on $D$ for the existence of a topology $T$ on $X$ such that

- $(X,T)$ is Hausdorff
- D is dense in X
- $(X,T)$ is a Topological vector space.

Comment: Do you require more conditions on your topology than simply being Hausdorff? Otherwise I think that for $X = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ any subset $D$ with the cardinality of the continuum should work. The idea is to find a bijection of $X$ sending $D$ to (a subset of $X$ containing) $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is dense under the product topology. Then pulling back the product topology through this bijection you should obtain a Hausdorff topology on $X$ making $D$ dense.

Comment: @LouisHainaut Actually, what I'm trying to ask is if $D$ isn't too "bad" then how to get density.  In the examples I have in mind, $D$ can be rather small (but not too small).

Comment: Actually with my "pathological" topologies I think I can find a Hausdorff one for any infinite subset $D$, replacing the set $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with $\oplus_{\mathbb{N}}{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is countable and (I think) dense in the product topology. Obviously if $D$ is finite it cannot be dense in any Hausdorff topology. However I am not sure that you would be happy with such pathological topologies, so maybe you want to add conditions to prevent the topologies to be "too bad"

Comment: @LouisHainaut I tried to clarify my question (with some of your insights).  What I'm trying to ask is that if D is given, then when can we guarantee a Hausdorff topology on X.

Comment: I am afraid your edit does not really have an impact on my comments. In my opinion if the only requirement you impose on the topology is to be Hausdorff then the minimal requirement on D is to be infinite. You can construct the topology by choosing a countable subset $D'$ of $D$ and a bijection $\phi$ of $X$ sending $D'$ to a countable dense subset of $X$. Then you declare that a subset $U$ is open in this new topology if and only if its image $\phi(U)$ is open in the original topology (the one according to which $X$ is separable).

Comment: You're right.  This is now trivial!  Thank you for pointing this out Louis.  I'll post an answer then incorporating these ideas shortly :)

Comment: Do you require $X$ to be a Hausdorff topological vector space?

Comment: Preferably yes.  I'll add that in the post.

Comment: This does not clarify things. You ask whether there **exists** a topology $T$ on $X$ having suitable properties. But you begin with the statement "Let $X$ be a separable infinite-dimensional vector space". This means that $X$ already has some  topology $T^*$ such that $(X,T^*)$ is separable. You cannot expect that the given $D$ is dense with respect to $T^*$. Your question indicates that you look for **another topology** $T$ making $D$ dense. So what are the requirements on $(X,T^*)$?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue.  I meant to state that $X$ should have countable (algebraic) basis; my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition is that $D$ should not span a finite dimensional sub-space, because finite dimensional sub-spaces of Hausdorff vector spaces are all closed. Hence you need infinitely many linearly independent elements of $D$. **This is the only condition**. If $D$ has an infinite linearly independent subset then there is Hausdorff topology on $X$ in which $D$ is dense.

To show this lets throw out any dependencies and assume that $D$ is a countable linearly independent subset. Additionally I will assume that $D$ spans $X$, ie is a basis, which will simplify the argument a little but is not needed.

For notation $c_0(\Bbb N)$ is the space of complex sequences converging to $0$ endowed with the norm $\|v\|=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|(v)_n|$. We will embed $X$ into $c_0(\Bbb N)$ in a way that makes $D$ dense. We begin with a lemma:

> **Lemma** Let $K$ be a countable linear independent sub-set of $c_0(\Bbb N)$ and $v\in c_0(\Bbb N)$. Then there is a sequence $v_n\in c_0(\Bbb N)$ with $v_n\to v$ and $\{v_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup K$ is linearly independent.

You could for example let $(v_n)_k=(v)_k$ for $k=1,...,n$ and then have a "tail" of magnitude $1/n$. There is a lot of "space" in choosing this tail so that everything remains linearly independent, simply because the "infinite" elements of $c_0(\Bbb N)$ span a vector space of uncountable dimension.

Next suppose $D$ is enumerated and let $L= \mathrm{span}_{\Bbb Q}\{d_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$. This is a countable set because it is a countable union of countable sets:
$$L=\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \mathrm{span}_{\Bbb Q}\{ d_n\mid 1≤n≤N\}.$$
Additionally it will be will be dense in $X$ for any Hausdorff topology on $X$, this is because if $x= a_1 d_{n_1}+...+a_N d_{n_N}$ then $\mathrm{span}\{ d_1,...,d_{n_N}\}$ is a finite dimensional Hausdorff vector space and as such if $q_{i,k}\to a_i$ as $k\to\infty$ you have that $\sum_i q_{i,k} d_{n_i}\to \sum_i a_i d_{n_i}=x$, where $\sum_i q_{i,k}d_{n_i}\in L$.

Now we will be keeping track of cardinalities. Let $i_0:\Bbb N\to \Bbb Q$ be an enumeration. Next let $v$ be an element of $c_0(\Bbb N)$. Inductively use the Lemma to get for each $n\in\Bbb N$ a countable set of vectors $V_{0,n}$ so that $\bigcup_{n≤N}V_{0,n}$ is linearly independent and $V_n$ has a sequence converging to $i_0(n)\cdot v$.

Now let $i_1:\Bbb N\to \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Q\cdot V_{0,n}$ be an enumeration. By induction we again build countable sets $V_{1,n}$ so that $V_{1,n}$ contains a sequence approximating $i_1(k)$ and so that
$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}V_{0,n}\cup \bigcup_{n≤N}V_{1,n}$$
is linearly independent. Continue in this way, you want $V_{k,n}$ to be able to approximate the $n$-th element of $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Q\cdot V_{k-1,n}$ for $\bigcup_{l<k, j\in\Bbb N}V_{l,j}\cup\bigcup_{j≤n}V_{k,j}$ to be linearly independent.

In the end
$$V=\bigcup_{n,k\in\Bbb N}V_{n,k}$$
will be a countable collection of linearly independent vectors in $c_0(\Bbb N)$ so that for every $v\in V$ and $q\in\Bbb Q$ there is a sequence in $V$ approximating $q\cdot v$. Now let $i: D\to V$ be a bijection. Then
$$T: X\to c_0(\Bbb N), \qquad \sum_{d\in D}a_d\ d\mapsto \sum_{d\in D}a_d i(d),$$
which is a linear bijection since the elements of $V$ are all independent. Pull back the norm of $c_0$ to $X$ via $T$ to get a Hausdorff topology on $X$ in which $D$ is dense.

---

In the event that $D$ should not be a basis this procedure still works. You must just also approximate the the $\Bbb Q$ span of the missing basis elements by elements of $D$, this will not break any countability constructions.