# Density of a subspace in certain topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, limits-colimits

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}},(f_{i,j})_{i\leq j \in \mathbb{N}})$ be an inverse system in $Top$ with inclusion $\iota_i:U \hookrightarrow X_i$ for all $i$, such that $f_{i-1,i}\circ\iota_i=\iota_{i-1}$. Therefore, we consider $U$ as a subspace of $X_i$. Let $X:=\varprojlim_{i \in \mathbb{N}}X_i$.

I found in the comments of [Inverse Limit of Dense Subsets is Dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043803/inverse-limit-of-dense-subsets-is-dense) that if $U$ is dense in $X_i$ then it is dense in $X$, but I don't see why.

1st EDIT : My confusion was solved by the first comment. Nevertheless, my first question is

(1) Is $U$ dense in $X$ if $U$ is dense in $X_i$ for all $i$?

At next I am interested under which circumstance the converse holds.

(2) So if $U$ is dense in $X$, when is $U$ dense in $X_i$ for all $i$?

2nd EDIT: We can assume that each $X_i$ is a $K$-Banach space, i.e. $X$ is a Fréchet-space and $U$ is a subvector space. Not sure if this changes something.

Comment: In the present form your question does not make much sense. Note that the mentioned comments only deal with a very special case (all $X_n = \mathbb Q$, at least I understood it  in that way). In your question you tacitly assume that all $X_i$ contain  the same subspace $U$ (which is of course possible), but you miss to say what the maps $f_{i,j}$ do with $U$. Perhaps you want that $f_{i,j} \mid_U = id$? You should clarify this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it.